# Kickstarter for an Open Sourced ASIC

Tags: asic, mining-hardware

I've had some discussions with my colleagues at CU Boulder and we might be interested in developing an open sourced ASIC for Bitcoin mining. If I was to start a Kickstarter project, then who would support it and for how much?

Edit:

My goal is to answer two questions:

*I'm betting this question will answer two specific questions. First, why the ASIC open sourced project failed and second further explain the ASIC miner design process. There is currently a low level of understanding in the Bitcoin community about ASIC mining clients outside that they are orders of magnitude faster than GPUS.*

Comment: Hi Charles--although I'm glad you got a solid expert answer here, these sorts of questions probably fair better on a place like bitcointalk.org since it's sort of open ended and discussion oriented.  The stack exchange is mainly for compiling reference questions about factual queries, so chances are this question will be closed.  Nothing personal, just wanted to fill you in!

Comment: I'm betting this question will answer two specific questions. First, why the ASIC open sourced project failed and second further explain the ASIC miner design process. There is currently a low level of understanding in the Bitcoin community about ASIC mining clients outside that they are orders of magnitude faster than GPUS.

Comment: Mind editing those two questions into your post?  I agree they're worth answering.